# Localhost webpage not loading in Node.js without any error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, localhost

I am trying to run my localhost node.js server but it is not loading in any browser, i am not getting any error as well just a buffering symbol on the browser. My code is running fine on VS Code. Here is the code:

server.js code:

```
const http = require("http");
const app = require("./app");

const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer();

server.listen(port);
```

app.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "it works!",
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is not working for any node.js code

[VS Code is running fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8MRc.png)
[No error or nothing is being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOK8K.png)

Same thing is happening for my html pages, images attached below:
[HTML page when clicked on Go Live, but it works if i double click the file directly without vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOKHU.png)

Please help me out

I tried many things but it just won't work, I re-installed node.js, I did reset my networks as well I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue in the code, something is wrong with my device settings but I am unable to figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined app in server.js and never used. Simply you can use the below in the server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello, World!" });
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Ive also added err to capture error.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you should pass your Express App to createServer

```js
const http = require("http");
const app = require("./app");

const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```